# Maven shade plugin: How can I shade transitive dependencies of 3rd party dependency

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

**Input**

I am developing an infrastructure that uses Kafka Clients 0.11 (KC-0.11). KC-0.11 has it's own dependencies off course.

Project X aims to use my infra. Project X also uses a different infra which uses Kafka Client 0.8 (KC-0.8). Obviously, KC-0.8 has it's own dependencies (similar to KC-0.11 only with earlier versions...)

I need project X to be able to work with **both** KC-0.8 and KC-0.11.
For that I used maven shade plugin, where (in my infra) I shaded KC-0.11 within my jar.

**Problem**

The shading is performed **ONLY** for the KC-0.11 and not for KC-0.11's dependencies, but I need to shade the transitive dependencies of KC-0.11 as well.
(I must shade KC-0.11's transitive dependencies so that KC-0.8 could work as before with it's original dependencies. KC-0.8 cannot work with advanced versions of it's dependencies)

**Questions**

1. How can I shade transitive dependencies of KC-0.11 within my jar, without picking them one by one manually ?
2. Generally speaking: shouldn't this be the default option in case of shading ? doesn't it make sense that each time I am shading a 3rd party I would need also have to shade all it's (transitive) dependencies in order to assure it remains work properly ?

Comment: This is a very valid question. I'm also waiting for an answer to this.